# How to directly open this link in a player

Tags: javascript, html

This the URL that I made to open a rtml stream in a player.

```
<pre>
<href>
   http://mytv.dialog.lk/APTV3_WAP_WEB/PlayOrSubRedirector.action?network=3G&allParams=live,1,SER_190,Sirasa_TV,,,yes,PITEM_8,PDATA_15,no
</href>
</pre>
```

But when I click on the link it does not open in a player and just show me the made rtmp link like this.

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<url>
rtsp://10.62.230.21:554/livefeed/TENSPORTS_QVGA.sdp?msd=94775447908&pi=PITEM_233&pd=PDATA_234&sn=Ten&Sport&b=3G&os=WAP&cn=&m=GT-I9505&mcc=&mnc=&v=1.14&lac=&cid=&op=Dialog&st=1&sid=&pid=&stamp=3662542897&sign=f25fd0ca6192b5864c4b236f88252e0f
</url>
```

So how to open this link in a default player? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose each player has its own link type but for example for vlc player you can do something like:

```
<a href="vlc://http://your/service?token=xyz">link</a>
```

Comment: Can you please show me a example using my <href> because I have no idea what are you supposing please!